# Jquery Graph to display Engine Status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, highcharts

I need to draw a graph to display engine status.That is i will be having time like 1-2,2-3,3-4 along axis and by using bar graph i need to display whether engine was on or off at these time.

That is from 1-2 if it is off it will how black and 2-4 if it is on it will show blue color and again if the status is changed it should show black from blue.Right now i have customised  jquery high charts for displaying one bar,by removing some parameters.

I need to know how i implment this here or is it possible in this graph?

[image]

Comment: This type of chart is called a `gantt` chart. It is doable in highcharts but you need to do a bit of coding as it is not supported out of the box (yet). See http://www.highcharts.com/support/roadmap

Comment: See the gannt chart http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart and column range: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a column range chart, with minimal fudging.

The main issue is making sure you set your data points correctly, and to set `grouping:false` in the plotOptions.  The x value needs to be specified for each data as well, or else they will all be given a separate x value

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/o9ck2zLn/

This can easily be adapted to a time axis by supplying the timestamps as the y values.